# Insert value into dataframe easily in R

Tags: r, matching

Consider the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(0,0,0))
```

I want to easily put a value into the dataframe. Let's say I want the number 1 for "Agriculture". Of course, in this case I could easily do it by:

```
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(1,0,0))
```

But I have a huge dataframe, so it is not that easy to do. Instead is it possible that I could write:

```
change <- c("Agriculture", 1)
```

And then if it is macthing, then it will update df. But how do I do that? It should be possible for me to change multiple cells (for instance, both "Agriculture" and "Fishery") at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

You could write down a list of the industries you want to update, then use `%in%` operator inside a `mutate` function:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(0,0,0))

list_of_industries <- c("Agriculture","Fishery")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Industry %in% list_of_industries,
                        1,
                        0))
```

Output:

```
     Industry Value
1 Agriculture     1
2     Fishery     1
3    Industry     0
```

Comment: Thx! However, if I want to change "Agriculture" to 1, and "Fishery" to 2, how do I do that? :-)

Comment: @Michael You can use the `case_when` statement: `mutate(Value = case_when(Industry == "Agriculture" ~ 1, Industry == "Fishery" ~ 2, TRUE ~ 0))`

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
df$Value[df$Industry == "Agriculture"] <- 1

     Industry Value
1 Agriculture     1
2     Fishery     0
3    Industry     0
```

and

```
df$Value[df$Industry %in% c("Agriculture", "Fishery")] <- 1
     Industry Value
1 Agriculture     1
2     Fishery     1
3    Industry     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a merge and inplace update using `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

# set df as dt
dt <- data.table(df)

# update table
updt <- fread(text="
  Industry,New_Value
  Agriculture,1
  Fishery,2
")

# temporary merge on Industry column to fetch new value
# and inplace update dt
dt[
  updt, on="Industry", # merging
  Value := New_Value # inplace update
]
```

Got

```
      Industry Value
1: Agriculture     1
2:     Fishery     2
3:    Industry     0
```